# ActionScript 3.0: myClass extends Button not working

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash-cc

I am newbie to `Actionscript` 3.0 so any help will be greatly appreciated. I am trying to get into `AS3` and class definitions, so I created a `myButtonClass` extends Button to build buttons dynamically. However, when the button appears on the `SWF` it cant be clicked, looks like inactive, with no animation at all. I know that I can extend myClass with MovieClip and do all the respective scripting, but I want to understand why it is not working the way I am doing it. Moreover, to make it work I had to add the built-in button to my Library so the needed parts to build the button can be used by the compiler. Here's the script:

```
package code {

    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Boton extends Button {

        public function Boton() {
            setupBoton("My button");
        }

        function setupBoton(texto: String): void {
            super.label = texto;
            super.x = 400;
            super.y = 100;
            super.width = 100;
            super.height = 25;
            super.enabled = true;
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changeLabel);


        }
        function changeLabel(event: MouseEvent): void {

            super.label = "Label changed";

        }

    }

}
```

What am I missing???

sincerely,

Lorenzo

Comment: just a quick tip.  I've seen it suggested to code solely in English.  You obviously know English quite well, and while the code you posted should be pretty easy to understand notwithstanding the Spanish in it, English only can help people understand more quickly what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: How are you using that class?

Comment: I think you must implement a custom skin for your button class

Comment: There is no errors at all, I've even tested it! It's pretty much clickable and correctly changes the label on the first click once and forever! Please elaborate more on your situation!

Comment: Not sure how the button class look like in pure actionscript version but don't you need a super(); in your public function Boton()?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses... I have edited my post to English-only, thank you for your  observation Neal.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses... I have edited my post to English-only, thank you @Neal Davis. I have two files, a FLA one and a AS one. The FLA file has nothing except the Button object in the library.The Class Boton is inside a Boton.as file, which is linked to the FLA using the  properties window of the stage, field Class.  I wonder if someone can tell me how to build a myclass extends Button the way I want to do. I have see many posts in which SimpleButton, Sprite, MovieClip and some other classes are used to build buttons, so I wonder why nobody uses Button class to make buttons.

Comment: Maybe the answer is in the response of @Joe Taras...can you give me more directions on how to implement skins, please?

Comment: Make your own button class extend Sprite. The simple button that comes with flash is just that... simple. It's fine for getting something up and running but I haven't known anyone to suggest using them for your actual project.